# Yad Button closed

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, yad

**I have this code:**

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
choice=$(yad --title="Vyberte si prosím produkčnú ES" \
--borders=20 --text="<span foreground='black'><b><big><big>Vyberte si prosím program na výpočet produkčnej ES:</big></big></b></span> \n \n "   \
--form --field="<span font='10' foreground='green'><b>Biomasa - poľnohospodárske plodiny (P1)</b></span>":BTN "echo 1" \
--form --field="<span font='10' foreground='#E17817'><b>Biomasa - drevo a prírodné vlákna (P2)</b></span>":BTN "echo 2" \
--form --field="<span font='10' foreground='blue'><b>Pitná voda (P3)</b></span>":BTN "echo 3" \
--form --field="<span font='10' foreground='#F50FE6'><b>Úžitokvá voda (P4)</b></span>":BTN "echo 4" \
--form --field="<span font='10' foreground='#1DC4C6'><b>Voľne žijúca zver / prírodné plodiny (P5)</b></span>":BTN "echo 5")

echo "$choice"
```

But when I click the button nothing will happen, I need after clicking on some button to close the window and send value 1 to 5 to the variable $choice. Thank you for any advice.

Comment: --form will only output data that the user inputs in the form. Try --list to display options among which a user can choose.

Comment: Thak you for you advice :)

Comment: Sadly, this can't be done. Form buttons always call a function and cannot terminate the yad box, so your script could be adapted to perform functions for each button but it would leave the yad box open until exit is pressed. See https://cjungmann.github.io/yaddemo/docs/yadbuttons.html#form-buttons

Answer (score 0):

Further to my comment, I did some experimenting and came up with this script, which I believe does exactly what you want. While the documentation says that a form must call a function, with my version of yad, which is 0.40.0 (GTK+ 3.24.33), a 'bash -c {command}' works. As for not being able to close the yad dialogue after an option is selected, I got round this by killing the process using the YAD_PID variable.

```
#!/bin/bash
choice=$(yad --title "Vyberte si prosím produkčnú ES" \
--borders=20 --no-buttons \
--text "<span foreground='black'><b><big><big>Vyberte si prosím program na výpočet produkčnej ES:</big></big></b></span> \n \n "   \
--form --columns 1 \
--field="<span font='10' foreground='green'><b>Biomasa - poľnohospodárske plodiny (P1)</b></span>:FBTN" 'bash -c "echo 1;kill $YAD_PID"' \
--field="<span font='10' foreground='#E17817'><b>Biomasa - drevo a prírodné vlákna (P2)</b></span>:FBTN" 'bash -c "echo 2;kill $YAD_PID"' \
--field="<span font='10' foreground='blue'><b>Pitná voda (P3)</b></span>:FBTN" 'bash -c "echo 3;kill $YAD_PID"' \
--field="<span font='10' foreground='#F50FE6'><b>Úžitokvá voda (P4)</b></span>:FBTN" 'bash -c "echo 4;kill $YAD_PID"' \
--field="<span font='10' foreground='#1DC4C6'><b>Voľne žijúca zver / prírodné plodiny (P5)</b></span>:FBTN" 'bash -c "echo 5;kill $YAD_PID"')
echo "Choice was $choice"
```

Two years too late, but maybe it will help someone!